# Apply opencv Homography to Three.js planes

Tags: opencv, three.js, homography, image-stitching

so I am trying to make a panorama in the browser out of 6 videos taken from 6 cameras. the stitching is done with `OpenCV` in `python` and that gives me back the homographies. How can I apply the homographies to 6 `Three.js` planes so that I get the same result as `OpenCV` ? and is it possible to extract the translations/rotations from a homography so that I can apply it to the plane? 
Thanks a lot!